# Why is 23 this summation's upper limit?

Tags: probability, combinations

Can someone explain why $12$ and $23$ are the lower and upper limits for the series equation in the answer to this question:

- [BlackJack Card Probability when Counting Cards](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2821389/blackjack-card-probability-when-counting-cards/2824703#2824703?newreg=a22e67394d164700a063ebd342d13bfa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bounds on $c$ are due to counting neutral cards. If $c\gt23$ then $47-2c\lt0$, and if $c\lt12$, then $47-2c\gt23$, but there are at most $24$ neutral cards.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: $47-2c$ should not get negative.

Longer answer: the index $c$ is the number of high cards. If you have $c=23$ high cards, then you have $28$ low cards, which is possible. But $24$ high cards means there are $29$ low cards, but there are only $52$ cards in total.